# Tensorflow 2.4.0: How do I access a layer attribute from another layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, layer

How can I access a layer's attributes from inside another layer? Below is how I have been trying to do this task.

I'm trying to do what I would call Sample-wise MinMax Scaling which, as one might guess, MinMax Scales across each sample as opposed to down each feature. This is for an autoencoder, so that means the initial scaling parameters need to be "saved" or rather accessible to another different layer that reverses the scaling (or descales). Also, since this kind of scaling depends on an individual sample's minimum and maximum, it must be done "live" whether during training or prediction/inference, and the minmax parameters for each sample must be in the same order as the samples they are associated with because, once again, this is sample-wise minmax scaling.

I have tried finding information elsewhere, but information that I have found is either for Tensorflow 1.x or suggested using standard methods for accessing attributes of normal python class objects. I have found a few questions worded similarly, but they don't directly apply to my situation.

I have successfully built a number of different scaling layers, but none of have had to access a layer attribute from outside that layer.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as krs
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

(x,y),(xtest,ytest) = tf.keras.datasets.boston_housing.load_data()
print(x.shape)
# x[:,-1] = 0
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler2 = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(x)
scaler2.fit(x.T)
print(scaler.data_min_.shape)
transformed = scaler.transform(x)
transformed2 = scaler2.transform(x.T).T

class SampleMinMaxScaler( krs.layers.Layer ):
    def __init__(self, limits = (0.,1.), name="SampleMnMxScale" ):
        super(SampleMinMaxScaler, self).__init__()
        self.limits = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(limits),dtype='float64')
        self.range = tf.constant(limits[1]-limits[0],dtype='float64')
        self.range_min = tf.constant(limits[0],dtype='float64')
        self.max_data = tf.zeros((5,10),dtype='float64')
        self.min_data = tf.zeros((5,10),dtype='float64')
        # tf.print(self.limits.get_shape())
        # self.name = name
        
        

    def build(self, input_shape):
        pass

    def call(self, input):
        super(SampleMinMaxScaler, self).__init__()
        # input_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(input,dtype='float64')
        input_data = tf.cast(input,dtype='float64')
        self.max_data = tf.math.reduce_max(input_data,axis=1)
        self.min_data = tf.math.reduce_min(input_data,axis=1)
        
        self.inv_denominator = tf.divide(tf.constant(1.,dtype='float64'), tf.subtract(self.max_data,self.min_data) )
        self.inv_denominator = tf.where(tf.math.is_inf(self.inv_denominator),tf.constant(0.,dtype='float64'),self.inv_denominator)
        
        self.scaling_multiplier = tf.multiply(self.inv_denominator,self.range)
        
        return tf.transpose(tf.cast(tf.add( tf.multiply( tf.subtract(tf.transpose(tf.cast(input,dtype='float64')), self.min_data), self.scaling_multiplier ), self.range_min ),dtype='float32'))
    
    def get_config(self):
        data = {    'limits': self.limits,
                    'range': self.range,
                    'range_min': self.range_min}
        return data

class SampleMinMaxDescaler( krs.layers.Layer ):
    def __init__(self, max_data, min_data, limits, input_range, name="SampleMnMxDescale" ):
        super(SampleMinMaxDescaler, self).__init__()
        self.max_data = max_data 
        self.min_data = min_data
        self.limits = limits
        self.range = input_range
        # tf.print(input_range.get_shape())
        self.range_min = limits[0]
        # self.name=name
        

    def build(self, input_shape):
        pass

    def call(self, input):
        
        inv_denominator = tf.divide(tf.constant(1.,dtype='float64'), self.range)
        
        scaling_multiplier = tf.multiply(inv_denominator,tf.subtract(self.max_data,self.min_data))
        
        return tf.transpose(tf.cast(tf.add( tf.multiply( tf.subtract(tf.transpose(tf.cast(input,dtype='float64')), self.range_min), scaling_multiplier ), self.min_data ),dtype='float32'))

    def get_config(self):
        data = {    'limits': self.limits,
                    'range': self.range,
                    'range_min': self.range_min}
        return data

inputs = krs.Input(shape=(x.shape[1],))    
samp_scaler = SampleMinMaxScaler()
outputs = samp_scaler(inputs)
outputs2 = SampleMinMaxDescaler(samp_scaler.max_data,samp_scaler.min_data,samp_scaler.limits,samp_scaler.range )(outputs)

model = krs.models.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs2 )

model.compile(optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x)
out = model.predict(x)
# print((out-transformed2)/(transformed2+1e-12)*100)
print((out-x)/(x+1e-12)*100)
```

However, below is the error that is produced from this code. I honestly have no idea what it means. I have searched for information on it, but it is very unclear how it's supposed to work/help. I have tried putting it inside the both the `SampleMinMaxScaler.__init__()` and `SampleMinMaxDescaler.__init__()` functions separately and both at the same time, but none of those attempts worked.

```
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
   @tf.function
   def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
     added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: model_104/sample_min_max_scaler/Max:0.
```

Lastly, I am aware I could scale and descale outside of the model with numpy/sklearn, and, in fact, that is what I have been doing. The reason I am building these scaling/descaling layers is that I am trying to perform transfer leaning that links three separate models together end to end. They are, of course, initially trained separately, but since each middle model was trained on the output of the first model to create the expected input of the last model, and each model has its own scaling/descaling steps that need to be implemented in the combined model.

The TLDR of the last paragraph is "using numpy and/or sklearn outside of the model is not a valid option." Also, using GradientTape isn't an option for reasons that are not relevant to problem at hand.

Edit: I had made a stupid mistake which is now corrected in both this post and the code; however, I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: The problem is that your two models can't be interconnected: they have a different computational graph. I don't exactly understand your requirements, so I will advise you to look at this guide, it might help you: [Customize what happens in Model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit)

Comment: @Lescurel - I'm a bloody fool. Thank you for pointing that out. I was copying and pasting code from those aforementioned scaling/descaling layers, and I had it in my head that it would work the same way. I will report back on this once I test it.

Comment: @Lescurel - I did fix that issue as far as I can tell, but it didn't fix the overall problem. I'm still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to reuse the layer to perform the descaling op. You don't need to pass around variables between layers that way. You just need to make sure that you're calling the scaler before the descaler, and only once.

Something akin to this:

```
class SampleMinMaxScaler(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, limits=(0.0, 1.0), name="SampleMnMxScale"):
        super(SampleMinMaxScaler, self).__init__()
        self.limits = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(limits), dtype="float64")
        self.range = tf.constant(limits[1] - limits[0], dtype="float64")
        self.range_min = tf.constant(limits[0], dtype="float64")
        self.max_data = tf.zeros((5, 10), dtype="float64")
        self.min_data = tf.zeros((5, 10), dtype="float64")

    def scale(self, input):
        input_data = tf.cast(input, dtype="float64")
        self.max_data = tf.math.reduce_max(input_data, axis=1)
        self.min_data = tf.math.reduce_min(input_data, axis=1)

        inv_denominator = tf.divide(
            tf.constant(1.0, dtype="float64"), tf.subtract(self.max_data, self.min_data)
        )
        inv_denominator = tf.where(
            tf.math.is_inf(inv_denominator),
            tf.constant(0.0, dtype="float64"),
            inv_denominator,
        )

        scaling_multiplier = tf.multiply(inv_denominator, self.range)

        return tf.transpose(
            tf.cast(
                tf.add(
                    tf.multiply(
                        tf.subtract(
                            tf.transpose(tf.cast(input, dtype="float64")), self.min_data
                        ),
                        scaling_multiplier,
                    ),
                    self.range_min,
                ),
                dtype="float32",
            )
        )

    def descale(self, input):
        inv_denominator = tf.divide(tf.constant(1.0, dtype="float64"), self.range)

        scaling_multiplier = tf.multiply(
            inv_denominator, tf.subtract(self.max_data, self.min_data)
        )

        return tf.transpose(
            tf.cast(
                tf.add(
                    tf.multiply(
                        tf.subtract(
                            tf.transpose(tf.cast(input, dtype="float64")),
                            self.range_min,
                        ),
                        scaling_multiplier,
                    ),
                    self.min_data,
                ),
                dtype="float32",
            )
        )

    def call(self, input, descale=False):
        if descale:
            return self.descale(input)
        return self.scale(input)
```

And then building your model the following way:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(x.shape[1],))
samp_scaler = SampleMinMaxScaler()
scaled = samp_scaler(inputs)
descaled = samp_scaler(scaled, descale=True)
model2 = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=descaled)
```

Comment: Thank you! I did have questions about whether multiple calls would fail, but after testing, it appears to work flawlessly. Thanks again.